# Unable to wait for process

Tags: windows, vbscript

I had a Visual Basic script with something like this:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
WshShell.Run " cmd.exe", 8, True
```

Running it gave this error:

```
---------------------------
Windows Script Host
---------------------------
Script: D:\Folder\MyScript.vbs
Line:   2
Char:   1
Error:  Unable to wait for process.
Code:   80020009
Source:     WshShell.Run

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I did get an Explorer window opened.

Why is this?

Comment: What's your aim in this script ?

Comment: The aim is to start a program and wait for it to end. For the sake of simplicity I used the always available cmd.exe here, but that's irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command starts with a space (or a `vbTab`). Just trim it off and all will be fine.

Comment: there is no space in my command but still I am getting same error why?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this :

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "cmd /k",1,True
```

Or something like this :

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Command = "Ipconfig /all"
WshShell.Run "cmd /k " & Command & "",1,True
```

Comment: there is no space in my command but still I am getting same error why?